# "waiting for connections on port 27017" connecting to mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I"m getting this message when I run mongod.

In the tutorial I'm doing, I think I should be getting something like "connection accepted from 127.0.0.16:6.."

I checked out this post already - [mongod HostnameCanonicalizationWorker error on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818009/mongod-hostnamecanonicalizationworker-error-on-os-x)

and I have my hosts file set up as such:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1 Bens-MacBook-Pro.local
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

These are my scripts for Node:

```
// Main starting point of the application
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const router = require('./router');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// DB Setup

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:auth/auth');


// App Setup
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: '*/*' }));
router(app);

// Server Setup
const port = process.env.PORT || 3090;
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);

console.log('Server listening on:', port);
```

This is the log for mongod:

```
2016-11-20T16:33:13.095-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=15054 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Bens-MacBook-Pro.local
```

......

```
2016-11-20T16:33:13.380-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

What is missing?

Thanks!

***UPDATED***

http://code.runnable.com/UWxv-JS8trEHAACH/connect-to-mongodb-using-mongoosejs-for-node-js

I added a listener to check for connection:

```
/*
* More details here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html
*/

//require mongoose node module
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//connect to local mongodb database
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');

//attach lister to connected event
mongoose.connection.once('connected', function() {
    console.log("Connected to database")
});
```

And it is logging "Connected to database" so it *appears* to be connected even thought the mongod window says it's not. Let me go through the rest of the tutorial and see if it's truly connected.

Answer (score 1):

You are making some errors

- `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:auth/auth');` is looking for a port `:auth` that does not exist
- `const server = http.createServer(app);` you can simply do `app.listen(port);`
- `router(app);` you can simply do `require('yourRouteFile.js')(app);`

You should get it going with the following **server.js**

```
// Main starting point of the application
const express    = require('express');
const http       = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app        = express();
const morgan     = require('morgan');
const mongoose   = require('mongoose');
const port       = process.env.PORT || 3090;

// DB Setup
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/auth');

// App Setup
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: '*/*' }));

//Routes
require('yourRouteFile.js')(app);

// Server Setup
app.listen(port);

console.log('Server listening on:', port);
```

Comment: @AndrewM16. Thanks for getting back. I changed it to "mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/auth');" and it's still not connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So i followed the rest of the node + mongoose tutorial and using postman, I was able to save stuff to the db, verified by Robomongo. But my log with mongod still says "waiting for connections on port 27017". So I am not sure why.....But things work.